# Logging in using username and password

Tags: android

I am developing an android app. The app requires the user to log in using user name and password, for which he first needs to create it. After creating it, when he comes again, he should be able to log in.Is it necessary to have a server? what are alternate options available? How should i go about this?

Comment: you can do this both in local i.e sqlite or server db i.e your choice one...

Comment: You can use shared preference no need of server and all. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 3):

basically yes ..  but the databse is needed not to store the password but to create it ..  the logic of your app will require a valid username and password that are stored in a database and you will fetch them once from this databse .. after this , if the user entered correctly the username and password , he will store them internally using `sharedpreference` , so he wont have to reconnect again. that way next time he tries to login he will automatically by oass the authentification page